# Navigation drawer is not collapsing, no hamburger button is there

Tags: java, android, android-layout, navigation-drawer, drawerlayout

My drawer layout is showing as a normal activity without any button in the toolbar also its not collapsing in any way..I want it from right side.

This is my drawer activity layout..

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".myDrawer"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="#000"
            android:id="@+id/drawer_toolbar"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">

        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

        </FrameLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:foregroundGravity="left"
    app:menu="@menu/drawer_menu"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header">

</android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

**this is my nav_header.xml layout.**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="300dp"
    android:padding="15dp"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark">
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:src="@drawable/hhh"
    />
<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="pehli line"
    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"/>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="dusri line"
        android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

**This is drawer activity java**

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;

public class myDrawer extends AppCompatActivity {
Toolbar toolbar;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_my_drawer);

        toolbar=findViewById(R.id.drawer_toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    }
}
```

**Output of above code**-->

[image]

**but I want it a navigation drawer, that i can slide from left.**
Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace your navigation view with below

```
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header"
        app:menu="@menu/my_menu">
    </android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>
```

Add below method to display toggel

```
public void addToggel() {
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        //drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
        drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    }
```

Add below string in string.xml

```
<string name="navigation_drawer_open">open</string>
    <string name="navigation_drawer_close">close</string>
```

update drawer layout id and navigation view id as per your code

Let me know with more help

Comment: woooohooooooo it works...great... but why Why i dont have hamburger button at the top?
I want that button also..thanks buddy @hardik